# Can I get the relationships of a node using node_load()?

Tags: 7, nodes, search

I want to load relationships from the `node_load()`. So for example  getting the article content type and loading the author information with the same query.
How would I go about doing this?

The end goal is to make a computed field for Drupal Search API so that I can convert the field's name. The relationship fields are currently in the form `table_name:field_name` but I am indexing into Algolia and therefore need the field name to just be `field_name`.

Comment: I have not understand what is your end goal. Do you want to index multiple fields as fulltext?

Comment: @milkovsky My end goal is to add fields to a search index. So I need to have relationships within that search index. But the search index (Algolia) breaks when there are colons in the field name that is sent across. So I need to remove them

Comment: You can just index the rendered html

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by that? Is that something that is possible to do in Drupal 7?

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can index the entire rendered HTML of your content. 
Let's assume your index is called "default_node_index" and content type is "article".

1. Visit `/admin/config/search/search_api/index/default_node_index/workflow`
2. Enable "Complete entity view"
   [image]
3. Visit /admin/config/search/search_api/index/default_node_index/fields
4. Enable "Entity HTML output".
   [image]
5. Manage display of your content type /admin/structure/types/manage/article/display
6. Enable "Search Index" in "Custom display settings" fieldset.
   [image]
7. Visit /admin/structure/types/manage/article/display/search_index
8. Add all the fields you want to render. You can extend this display using the regulat hooks, templates and preprocesses if needed.